# Adding [Coordinate-System]

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently created the [coordinate-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system) tag and [created a wiki for it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/coordinate-system/info). It made sense and I feel like it's a good tag. What I *didn't realize* is how many questions could potentially be tagged with it. I created a search for it and discovered that there are over 200 candidate questions. While I *could* do all of this work myself, I don't want to blow up the front page. I prefer this work happen in small batches as not to disrupt it.

Doing the work this way will take some time, so I'm placing this question here to track the progress and  ask the community to help out a little bit.

[**Here is the list of candidate questions.**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=coordinates+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bcoordinate-system%5D)

Please remember to ***correct any and all issues*** with the questions you're adding the tag to. Also, it is just a list of *candidate* questions, so please be sure that this tag is not used for longitude & lattitude. [geospatial](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial) exists for that purpose.

---

It has since come to my attention that this may not be a good tag, so before I tag any more questions... ***Is this a good tag?***

Comment: Just from browsing the list of questions, I'm not sure if it's a great tag. It's definitely a good secondary tag but it really doesn't seem like a good fit to stand alone. If the questions were more mathematical it might make sense, but, with all of the different APIs/implementations/languages, the questions really don't appear to have a lot in common.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that this is still a little too specific, maybe the user doesn't see a coordinate system, or their coordinate system is something like HTML Coordinates, or CSS coordinates.

Why not something like [coordinate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate)?

Then we could rewrite some of those titles without the word coordinate in them, and it wouldn't be specific to any coordinate system.

It would be just broad enough

Comment: [HTML coordinates are just another coordinate system(s).](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp) (excuse the w3fools link, top hit on google...) Why not just add them to the tag wiki?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes. This is a good tag.

[coordinate-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system) adds value to the site.

*Please feel free to edit this wiki with your reasons supporting this tag.*

Answer (score -1):

## No. This is not a good tag.

[coordinate-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system) adds no value or actively harms this site.

*Please feel free to edit this wiki with your reasons against this tag.*